# PHP7 Bugs pcntl_signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN); how to kill zombies?

Tags: signals, fork, zombie-process, php-7, pcntl

If i run it:

```
<?php
    declare(ticks = 1);
    for($i=0;$i<300;$i++){
            $pid = pcntl_fork();
                if ($pid == -1) {
                     die('could not fork');
                } else if ($pid) {
                        usleep(2500);

                } else {
                        echo 'Child'.$i."\r\n";
                        sleep(mt_rand(1,3));

                        exit;
                }

    }
    echo 'Test123';
    pcntl_signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
    sleep(60)
    echo 'Test456';
?>
```

on PHP5. I see multiple `Child` and `Test123`, after 60 sec, I see `Test456`.

But! On PHP7, I see multiple `Child` `Test123` and not `Test456` - sleep doesn't work.

In production php-daemon I see `pcntl_signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);` don't help to kill zombie anymore! It doesn't work.

What I can do?

Comment: No idea if this will work, but `declare(ticks = 1);` maybe should be `declare(ticks=1);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$p = pcntl_waitpid(-1,$status,WNOHANG);
```

Without handler. In parent after create.

Answer (score -1):

Ok :) I finded answer :)

```
declare(ticks = 1);
```

- to top on script

that function to global:

```
    function signal_handler($signal) {
        switch($signal) {
            case SIGCHLD:
                while (pcntl_waitpid(0, $status) != -1) {
                    $status = pcntl_wexitstatus($status);
                    echo "Child $status completed\n";
                }

                exit;
        }
    }
```

This AFTER the fork in parent

```
pcntl_signal(SIGCHLD, "signal_handler");
```

Comment: oh no( its not working. If one process is die - script is cant work property :(